# Non-changeable navigation button

Tags: c#, xaml, design-patterns, uwp, modern-ui

#### Introduction

I downloaded a template of a **Universal Windows Platform (UWP)** application and started making changes right away.

#### Problem

When I try to change the button responsible for shortening the left navigation page, I cannot make a change.

[image]

#### Source Code

```
<Page
    x:Class="AVE_VSCODE_EXTENSION.Views.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:AVE_VSCODE_EXTENSION.Behaviors"
    xmlns:winui="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:helpers="using:AVE_VSCODE_EXTENSION.Helpers"
    xmlns:views="using:AVE_VSCODE_EXTENSION.Views"
    Loaded="OnLoaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <winui:NavigationView
        x:Name="navigationView"
        IsBackButtonVisible="Visible"
        IsBackEnabled="{x:Bind IsBackEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind Selected, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemInvoked="OnItemInvoked"
        IsSettingsVisible="True"
        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}">
        <winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <!--
            TODO WTS: Change the symbols for each item as appropriate for your app
            More on Segoe UI Symbol icons: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font
            Or to use an IconElement instead of a Symbol see https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/blob/release/docs/UWP/projectTypes/navigationpane.md
            Edit String/en-US/Resources.resw: Add a menu item title for each page
            -->
            <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Main" Icon="Globe" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:MainPage" />
            <winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_Chart" Icon="Admin" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:ChartPage" />
        </winui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior
                DefaultHeader="{x:Bind Selected.Content, Mode=OneWay}">
                <behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock
                                Text="{Binding}"
                                Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightMargin}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior.DefaultHeaderTemplate>
            </behaviors:NavigationViewHeaderBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="shellFrame" />
        </Grid>
    </winui:NavigationView>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to change the button responsible for shortening the left navigation page, I cannot make a change.

The shortening button of navigation page is `PaneToggleButton`, and it has independent style to descript the content, you could place the following style in your app's resource and edit the **Icon**
`Textblock` to approach like the following.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PaneToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewToggleBorderThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{ThemeResource PaneToggleButtonWidth}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource PaneToggleButtonHeight}" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Viewbox
                            x:Name="IconHost"
                            Width="16"
                            Height="16"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">

                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="Icon"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                Text="&#xE718;" />

                        </Viewbox>

                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />

                        <Border
                            x:Name="RevealBorder"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundChecked}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundChecked}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundCheckedDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```